# What language used in scala documentation in lexical expressions?

Tags: scala, expression

Here exampel from paragraph *1.3.1 Integer Literals* from scala documentation

```
integerLiteral ::= (decimalNumeral | hexNumeral) [‘L’ | ‘l’]
decimalNumeral ::= ‘0’ | nonZeroDigit {digit}
hexNumeral ::= ‘0’ ‘x’ hexDigit {hexDigit}
digit ::= ‘0’ | nonZeroDigit
nonZeroDigit ::= ‘1’ | ... | ‘9’
```

It **does not** seem like regular expression or SGML language.
Generally I understand what it means, but what the language is used for that?

Comment: Looks very similar, but do not see `::` in this article :(

Comment: Looks like EBNF or possibly just plain BNF (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus-Naur_Form) to me.  Read to the bottom of the article where use of `::=` in BNF is explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments it is [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).
Here is a proove with scala [gramma description](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/13-syntax-summary.html)